# What can I do to protect myself against Labyrinthitis recurral?

Tags: prevention, ear, frequency, vertigo

I recently suffered an extreme, but luckily short bout of [Labyrinthitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinthitis) and as described in that Wikipedia page, the doctor did not diagnose the cause, nor try and treat the underlying problem, but gave me anti-emetics and anti-vertigo medication to sort out the symptoms.

One warning I received was that the problem could recur, possibly multiple times, probably at lesser severity, and this worries me. This attack came on over the space of about 10 seconds while I was driving, and the worst symptoms lasted a week, preventing me walking or doing anything useful in that time. If it happens again while driving, my concern is that this time I may not be as lucky when braking hard and pulling over.

So is there anything I can do to prepare for it, be aware of symptoms, or prevent recurral, or at least reduce the severity?